# wm_title("message") is getting cut off by the tkinter window?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a simple tkinter window pop up (pastebin link : http://pastebin.com/kvv0G4rM). The problem I am facing is the title message ("Enter expenses") is cut off from the tkinter window which pops up .

I have tried resizing the size of the tkinter window and shift it to the center. In such case , the label , buttons everything does not completely fill the screen. (Try to comment out the height and size comments and the .geometry function call)

It looks like this

[The current scenario of the lables and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5bp5.png)

I am using grid as I have to dynamically add the rows for each "Add Expense" button press. See the function (add_row) . The index variable keeps the count of which number row the new entry field will be inserted into.

This question is similar to :-
[What controls automated window resizing in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997497/what-controls-automated-window-resizing-in-tkinter)

The only problem is when I resize it manually I lose the auto - resize behaviour. Which is necessary for my later half of the tkinter window behaviour(That is when I am adding new Entry fields on "Add Expense" button press.) .

I am including the codes :-

```
self.root = master
self.root.wm_title("Enter Expenses")
self.frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
self.frame.grid()
self.button = tkinter.Button(self.frame, 
                     text="QUIT", fg="red",
                     command=self.exit)
self.button.grid(row=0,column=0)
self.slogan = tkinter.Button(self.frame,
                     text="Add Expense",
                     command=self.create_expenseTable)
self.slogan.grid(row=0,column=1)

def create_expenseTable(self):
    global index
    global expenseReport
    self.frame.destroy()
    self.frame = tkinter.Frame()
    self.frame.grid()
    tkinter.Label(self.frame,text="Category").grid(row=index,column=0)
    tkinter.Label(self.frame,text="Amount").grid(row=index,column=1)
    index+=1

    self.e1 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)
    self.e2 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)

    self.e1.grid(row=index, column=0)
    self.e2.grid(row=index, column=1)
    index+=1
    self.create_button()

 def create_button(self):
    global index

    self.slogan = tkinter.Button(self.frame,
                     text="Add Expense",
                     command=self.add_row)
    self.slogan.grid(row=index,column=1)
    self.submit = tkinter.Button(self.frame,text="Submit Expense",command=self.endFunction)
    self.submit.grid(row=index,column=0)

def add_row(self):
    global index
    global expenseReport
    self.slogan.destroy()
    self.submit.destroy()
    category = self.e1.get()
    expense = self.e2.get()
    self.e1 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)
    self.e2 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)

    self.e1.grid(row=index,column=0)
    self.e2.grid(row=index,column=1)

    index+=1
    self.create_button()
```

The index increments for every button click of add_expense ; it then adds a new row and shifts the button a row lower.

What am I doing wrong ?
I want to make sure that all the contents of the window , fits the window (title bar etc) completely and does not get hidden when I resize.

Comment: What do you mean by "the title message ("Enter expenses") is cut off from the tkinter window which pops up"? Does it mean it's supposed to show both the category and the amount sections but it only shows the first one? Because that's what I've understood from the images you've provided above.

Comment: I have updated the images. Check the first image to see how Enter expenses show up when the window pop up.

Comment: Simply use `.geometry()` method for the root window. Add a value to it e.g: "500x100". The first one (500 in this case) is going to be the width of the root window.

Comment: Is there any way of auto resize ? If I use .geometry and give the dimension I require . I face the problem as in the pic 2. Here the text box and the quit and add expense button gets hidden or only a part of it is shown .

Comment: Please post a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) link that contains the whole working code here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kvv0G4rM , I have updated the question with my paste bin link . I am also commenting it here. It has the tkinter code (have not given the code for  the rest of the logic as it will confuse more) . Try commenting out the .geometry call to see what happens if I try to resize.

Comment: But it works fine for me: http://imgur.com/a/jfjVl

Comment: did you make the commented out part active ? I  m working in ubuntu  and it is something like this http://imgur.com/q4jTxTz

Comment: Ah, got it -- it looks awful now, like yours...

Comment: So actually you could've achieved it by: `root.geometry("300x100+500+50")`. But since you want to make it kinda responsive, you've gone through that way... The problem is that the screen parameters: `width`, `height`, `x`, `y` are not large enough. For example: I tried to print out these parameters and got these values: 200 30 583.0 369.0. As you can see these values are pretty far from 300 100 500 50 that I just wrote above.

Comment: BTW, my values are too big actually. Umm, what about changing the geometry line to this: `root.geometry('%dx%d-%d+%d' %(width+60,height+40,x,y))`? It works nice for me!

Comment: It is still cutting off the Buttons and the entry boxes. The responsiveness gets over written as soon as I use .geometry . And without using geometry there is no way I can fit the title message .

Comment: Try to change 60 and 40 to higher numbers maybe? And you should make its height dynamically increasing as you add a new expense. But that's another story. Tell me, did you use the exact same code I provided above? And did anything change? Or did anything not change at all?

Comment: I used root.geometry('%dx%d-%d+%d' %(width+60,height+40,x,y)). The size of the window increased and all . But the button still gets cut off mid way and all. As soon as I set the size in the code base, the auto resize capability of tkinter disappears ; so everytime I add a new row the window does not resize.

Comment: Does it work fine at first and after the first time you push the `Add Expense` button?

Comment: I told you that's another story that the responsivness disappears as you add more than one row. To solve it, you need to add a dynamically increasing height functionality to the `create_expenseTable` function. But first, let's figure out to make it work at first and after adding the first row.

Comment: Yes. I will try it out today post office. Will update the pastebin if successful.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment section, I incremented the height and width of the tkinter window for every add new row function call . This increased the responsiveness of the tkinter window size. 
I am pasting a dummy code that shows the increase of the window size for every "Add Expense" button click. Any kind of code review comments is highly welcomed.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tkinter
import sys

index = 0 
width = 0
height = 0   
x=0
y=0
class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.initialise_GUI(root)
        root.mainloop()

    def initialise_GUI(self,master):
        global height,width
        width = 304
        height = 30
        self.root = master
        width_screen = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        height_screen = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (width_screen/2)-(width/2)
        y = (height_screen/2)-(height/2)
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' %(width,height,x,y))
        self.root.wm_title("Expense Manager")
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.frame, 
                     text="QUIT", fg="red",width=15,
                     command=self.exit)
        self.button.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.slogan = tkinter.Button(self.frame,width=16,
                     text="Add Expense",
                     command=self.create_expenseTable)
        self.slogan.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy_application)

    def exit(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def create_expenseTable(self):
        global index,x,y,height,width
        width +=30
        height +=40
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.frame.grid()
        tkinter.Label(self.frame,text="Category").grid(row=index,column=0)
        tkinter.Label(self.frame,text="Amount").grid(row=index,column=1)
        index+=1

        self.e1 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)
        self.e2 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)

        self.e1.grid(row=index, column=0)
        self.e2.grid(row=index, column=1)
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' %(width,height,x,y))
        index+=1
        self.create_button()

    def create_button(self):
        global index
        global height
        global index
        height+=10

        self.slogan = tkinter.Button(self.frame,
                     text="Add Expense",
                     command=self.add_row)
        self.slogan.grid(row=index,column=1)
        self.submit = tkinter.Button(self.frame,text="Submit    Expense",command=self.exit)
        self.submit.grid(row=index,column=0)

    def add_row(self):
        global index
        global expenseReport
        global x,y,height,width
        height+=10
        self.slogan.destroy()
        self.submit.destroy()
        category = self.e1.get()
        expense = self.e2.get()
        self.e1 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)
        self.e2 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame)
        self.e1.grid(row=index,column=0)
        self.e2.grid(row=index,column=1)
        index+=1
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' %(width,height,x,y))
        self.create_button()
    """other code logic using category and expense"""

    def destroy_application(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        sys.exit(1)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = gui()
```